# Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS no DHCP on startup

Tags: server, 22.04, dhcp, dhclient

I am wondering if there has been a regression with Ubuntu.  Back when 18.04.3 came out, I noticed that my VM-based Ubuntu servers would no longer be able to get DHCP addresses from my Windows DHCP servers.  I posted about it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1298803/netplan-dhcp-not-working-2-minute-startup-delay-ubuntu-18-04/1374789).

21.10 seemed to resolve the issue, but of course, it is no longer supported.  I created some more VMs with 22.04.3 and they now have the same issue.  Stock install - everything seems to work, until you reboot.  Then you get a 2-minute timeout and no network until you run `sudo dhclient`.

If I run `ip a` it shows the ens160 interface with an altname of enp3s0 (that's new) but no IP.

I've modified my `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` to the following:

```
network:
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp-identifier: mac
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  version: 2
```

But it still won't connect until I manually get an IP after a reboot until I do `sudo dhclient`.  I also tried using the original ens160 in place of enp3s0 with no effect.

`sudo dmesg | grep dhcp` shows the following entries:

```
[    7.568386] audit: type=1400 audit(1668726304.016:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=742 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    7.568396] audit: type=1400 audit(1668726304.016:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=742 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

I know there was an AppArmor bug that caused this behavior before, and that was where the evidence was.  I don't know enough about the guts of Ubuntu to say if this is normal output or not, so I have included it.

Any help is much appreciated!  I'd love to be able to have new VMs not need a systemd workaround, that manually runs dhclient at startup, which is the workaround I'm using.

Comment: @heynnema - This is the new question.  I really thought we had this licked in 21.10.  Could there have been a regression?  Thank you again for your extensive knowledge!

Comment: I have a new VM I created in VirtualBox without this issue and a VM I got from VMware and converted and it does seem to have the same problem.  Confusing and very frustrating!